# Mongo db persistence in docker with volumes

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a mongo database container, but can't make the data to persist. 
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  mongodb:
  image: mongo:2.4
  command: --smallfiles 
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: mongodb_data_volume
      target: /data
volumes:
  mongodb_data_volume:
    external: true
```

After docker-compose, and exec -it into the mongodb, I create a new empty database and then I list the contents of the mounted volume:

```
root@cf8330019f91:/data/db# ls
_tmp     admin.1   journal  local.ns
admin.0  admin.ns  local.0  mongod.lock
```

But then I do a compose down and up cycle and the same mounted volume is reset to the initial values.

```
root@d18bda47d0b3:/data/db# ls
_tmp  journal  local.0  local.ns  mongod.lock
```

I've tried to only stop the container instead compose down, and then the data persisted... which would indicate that I'm still using the internal storage. If this is the case, how do I make it to use the external volume?

I'm using a mac and docker version 18.06.1-ce-mac73.

Comment: did you create the `mongodb_data_volume` outside of docker compose? the docs state docker compose wont try to create a volume if the external flag is set to true: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external

Comment: yes, the volume was created before

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have replicated same issue in my local system and try to resolve it,I have modified the target path in the docker-compose volume from "target: /data" to "target: /data/db" as per the documentation given in https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/ and it works. Use updated docker-compose file as given below

```
    version: "3.2"
    services:
      mongodb:
      image: mongo:2.4
      command: --smallfiles 
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: mongodb_data_volume
          target: /data/db
    volumes:
      mongodb_data_volume:
        external: true
```

Tested and works !!!

Comment: thank you! I guess if I want the configurations as well, then I should add a new volume mapped to the config folder... anyway, good spot!

Comment: I've a question: What is the best solution between: 

 volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: mongodb_data_volume
          target: /data/db

- VS - 

volumes: 
- "local-dir:docker-dir"

Answer (score 0):

I have created a mongodb container, with persistent storage using the following `docker-compose.yml` file trimmed down to the basics.
I am using a official mongo image version and map the database data stored in the container under `/data/db` to a local folder `/data` as below:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.2.2-bionic
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 27017-27019:27017-27019
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
```

Comment: when I try this I get `***aborting after fassert() failure` and `exited with code 14`.  However, a bunch of files and a `journal` directory are created in my local `/data`

Comment: @r_zelazny did you forget the dot in `./data`? Or does the folder already exist for some other purpose? Or are you using Windows? I just tried this `docker-compose.yml` file on Ubuntu 18.04 box and it worked for me without the errors you described.

Comment: Too late to edit my original comment, but it also works for me on Windows 10 Pro.